# viewにaddSubViewしたUIButtonが表示されません。

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

viewcontrollerの中身です[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これがviewの状態です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

UIButtonが表示されません。
これはなぜか教えていただきたいです。。

(ちなみに、btn1をmainViewにaddSubViewしたら、btnViewの裏に表示されました。)

Comment: コードは画像ではなくテキストとしてご提示ください。テキストとすることにより、検索が容易になる、コードを再利用して原因を特定したり回答を書くのが容易になる、等のメリットがあります。ご自身の質問は「編集」できるはずですので、よろしくお願いします。(コード全体を選択した後編集領域にある`{ }`アイコンを使用することで、コードとして成形されて表示されます。)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

btn1のframeの設定がおかしいものと思われます。
具体的には次のコードが問題です。

```
btn1.frame = btnView.frame
```

このコードを実行すると、btnViewのframeをbtn1のframeに設定します。
btnViewのframeはselfのviewに対しての表示位置としては適正な情報ですが、btn1をbtnView内部に表示する際には正しい情報ではありません。

該当のコードを次のように修正することで適切に表示されます。

```
btn1.frame = btnView.bounds
```

UIViewのframeは、
自身が追加されている親Viewに対しての相対位置
を表します。

同様にUIViewのboundsは
自身の内部的な位置における相対位置
を表します。

frameとboundsに対してもっと理解を深めたい場合はApple Developerの次の資料を参照すると良いでしょう。
frame : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622621-frame
bounds : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622580-bounds